# How to create a transparent mask in Love2D

Tags: love2d

Since Love2D doesn't support SVG, I'm looking for other ways to create solid, compound shapes.  Anything that has straight edges can be drawn using a polygon, but I haven't yet found a way to mask an circle or ellipse, or in other words, subtract a circle or ellipse from the object being drawn.  Is this possible with Love2D?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer -- What I was calling a mask is called a stencil in Love2D.  See https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.stencil and [Make some black pixels transparent in Love2D](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61391/make-some-black-pixels-transparent-in-love2d).